# Add visible content on hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to know if there's a way to add content at the end of my div which is partially hidden.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: -180px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: 1s;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:hover .slide {
  transition: 1s;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:red;">
        test
    </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:blue;">
        test
    </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;">
        test
    </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:green;">
        test
    </p>
</div>
```

The thing is simple. It's a menu with 4 links. It's partially hidden, but on hover it's completely revealed. I wanted to add a little arrow on the visible part of the div. Is there a way to make it ?
I already try this :

```
.slide:after {
  content: '                 >';
}
```

Sure this works but I think there's a better way !

Comment: `id`s **must be unique!**

Comment: Ok I changed it but I think this is not helping here ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ID attribute must be unique, document-wide. If ever you feel the need to give multiple elements the same ID, you should probably be using a class instead.

---

You *can* use a pseudo element to achieve what you're looking for. Tinker with the numbers to get your desired 'arrow'. This uses the border triangle technique.

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -180px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    transition: 1s;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:hover .slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
.slide:after {
    position: absolute;
    border:6px solid transparent; /* Half the height of arrow */
    border-left:10px solid #fff; /* Width of arrow */
    border-right:0;
    top:8px; /* Arrow distance from top */
    right:2px; /* Arrow distance from right */
    content:'';
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:red;">test</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:blue;">test</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;">test</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:green;">test</p>
</div>
```

---

**Related**:

- [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7073484/1612146)

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right lines I think, just adding an absolute to the `:after` content does the trick:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;

}
.slide:after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: -180px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: 1s;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:hover .slide {
  transition: 1s;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="slide" style="background-color:red;">
    test
  </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="slide" style="background-color:blue;">
    test
  </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;">
    test
  </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="slide" style="background-color:green;">
    test
  </p>
</div>
```

If you want the arrow to disappear on hover, you can use:

```
.slide:hover:after {
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternate implementation of the `::after` pseudo-element, using it to create a 'border-triangle' shape, and positioning it `absolute` (the advantage of the 'border-triangle' over the use of the > is simply that it has a rather higher visibility):

```
.slide::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 0.5em solid transparent;
  border-left-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.slide:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: -180px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: 1s;
  text-align: center;
}
.slide::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 0.5em solid transparent;
  border-left-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.slide:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.wrapper:hover .slide {
  transition: 1s;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="slide" style="background-color:red;">
    test
  </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="slide" style="background-color:blue;">
    test
  </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;">
    test
  </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="slide" style="background-color:green;">
    test
  </p>
</div>
```

Note also that, while you've changed your posted code in the question, the use of a duplicate `id` immmediately invalidates your HTML; which is why I've used classes instead (as did you, in the edit to your question).

Answer (score 0):

change ids for class like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:red;">
        test
        <span>></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:blue;">
        test
        <span>></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:yellow;">
        test
        <span>></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="slide" style="background-color:green;">
        test
        <span>></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -180px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    transition: 1s;
    text-align: center;
}
.slide span {
    float:right;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.wrapper:hover .slide {
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tsoz57mt/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p id="slide" style=" background-color:red;">
        <span>test</span> 
        <span class='arrow'>></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p id="slide" style="background-color:blue;">
        <span>test</span> 
        <span class='arrow'>></span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p id="slide" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <span>test</span> 
        <span class='arrow'>></span>
    </p>

</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p id="slide" style="background-color:green;">
        <span>test</span> 
        <span class='arrow'>></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS----------------

```
.wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
width: 200px;
height: 30px; 
margin-top: 10px;
 }
.arrow{
float: right;
}
#slide {
position: absolute;
left: -180px;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
transition: 1s;
text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:hover #slide {
transition: 1s;
left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a border-image to your slide.
(please use class=slide instead of id=slide and change # to . in your css as mentioned)

```
.slide { 
 background-image: url('arrow.jpg');
 background-position: right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: block; /* make the link background clickable */
}
```